# A difficulty in understanding thm 4.8 in Schaum series "General Topology "

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I did not understand from where this step comes:
$$U_{p} \subset f^{-1}[f[U_{p}]] \subset f^{-1}[V]$$
Could anyone explain this for me? Any suggestion for an elementary book in general topology is so appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first inclusion $U_{p} \subset f^{-1}[f[U_{p}]]$ is a general statement from elementary set theory:

> Given sets $A,B$ and a function $f:A\to B$, if $U\subset A$ then $$U\subset f^{-1}[F[U]].$$

The proof of this is quite simple, just pick any element $x\in U$ and show that $x\in f^{-1}[f[U]]$.

The second inclusion $f^{-1}[f[U_{p}]] \subset f^{-1}[V]$ follows from the fact given in the proof that $f[U_p]\subset V$, and another fact from elementary set theory:

> Given sets $A,B$ and a function $f:A\to B$, if $U,V\subset B$ and $U\subset V$ then $f^{-1}[U]\subset f^{-1}[V]$.

As for a book on general topology, I have to recommend Munkres' *Topology*.  It begins with elementary set theory, then proceeds to topology by looking at the easier to understand metric space before moving onto the more abstract topological spaces.